# Disable 'Save changes' dialog in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

Every time I read a .pdf and try to exit, Reader asks me to save the changes (which of course, I had not the possibility to even make). How do I disable this dialog?

Edit - I use **X, updated to the latest build**.

Comment: Does this happen for each and every PDF? Or does it happen only with some specific PDFs? Do you have Javascript support enabled or disabled in your Reader?

Comment: This only happens for certain files sent over email. If I save the file (it only allows to save it as a new instance, as if it was read-only), this issue is gone.

Comment: change Security (Enhanced) settings as shown below:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977075/how-can-i-stop-adobe-reader-from-asking-save-as-when-saving-a-pdf-form-i-e-a)

Comment: @Martin does the answer in the following thread explain your problem ? https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/disable-quot-do-you-want-to-save-changes-before-closing-quot/m-p/9610320#M85197

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what version, but for version X I would try this:

- Go to *Edit -> Preferences -> Documents -> Save Settings* and uncheck both options.

I am not sure if that is it, but that was all I could find that seemed reasonable.

Comment: Not working for me. It seems that Adobe Reader "does not like" some PDF 1.2 and at exit would like to save it to 1.6 format.

Comment: I have read about this solution at several other websites, too. Unfortunately, some years later and with Acrobat Reader DC, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the previous answer doesn't work. I struggled with this for quite a while. It really is infuriating that a program that won't let you save keeps asking if you want to save. In the end the only thing I found that worked was getting rid of Adobe Reader and installing Foxit Reader. Finally, no more stupid dialog box every time I try to close a PDF.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me, using Adobe Reader XI (Version 11.0.0), was to respond to the dialog asking whether or not to save changes by choosing "Yes", then saving the PDF file on top of itself.  Thereafter,  I no longer saw the 'save changes' dialog when closing the file.  (The file I was having a problem with was downloaded from http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slab034w/slab034w.pdf.  Also, probably not relevant, but I'm running 64-bit Win7.)

Comment: Yes, but just to make this really clear: this will only work for that specific file.  If another file of similar properties is opened later, the save dialog will still be presented on closing that other file. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: This solution worked for me (some years later and with Acrobat Reader DC), so voted up. But I am concerned that the PDF's contents might be changed when saving it again. Eventually we should dump Acrobat Reader for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

The following change allows the Save button to work as Save, not Save As:

1. Go to Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced)
2. Turn off *Enable Protected Mode at Startup*

Comment: This solution works, but you may have an issue with malicious PDF documents if you're careless.

Comment: Some years later and with Acrobat Reader DC, that solution did not work for me.

Comment: Of all the solutions here, this is the only one that worked for me (with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, 2019.012.20035)