# Disable save changes dialoge in Adobe reader X

Tags: adobe-reader

Yes, I've read and done the steps listed here with no results:
[Disable 'Save changes' dialog in Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/questions/299153/disable-save-changes-dialog-in-adobe-)

Basically what happens is with certain PDF documents, whenever I try to close them, it prompts me to save changes.  This baffles me, as [per their FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/faq.html), Reader can't save anything, and I didn't make changes to the document in the first place.  The one cause I could think of would be that the documents may not have been created with Adobe software, and as such may not write the PDFs in a way that makes Adobe happy.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of Adobe Reader and installing [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) worked for me.

Finally, no more dialog box every time I try to close a PDF.